# Where/How to put an image on the internet so it can be pulled via Swift?

Tags: swift, image, asynchronous, swiftui-asyncimage

So I want to just pass in an image https://... url into AsyncImage but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to upload this image to the internet so that it can be pulled into the swift code. Any suggestions on free ways to upload the image would be greatly appreciated. I've tried stuff like Imgur but because there's other stuff in the html than the image, it can't pull it correctly.

Comment: show us the code that you have tried, a complete code, where it does not "work", the errors you get, etc... See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Firebase hosting might be a good place to start

Comment: Once uploaded to Imgur, control-click on the image to open in a new tab or window.  Then you'll have a link directly to the image.